Easiest way to query YTD account balances
I wanted to ask what the easiest way to query daily balances (non native token) of specific addresses on Solana backdating to the beginning of this year. It doesn't look like there are endpoints where we can do this easily. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!
